# blackberry css position: fixed

Tags: jquery, css, blackberry, css-position

I recently encountered a problem with my site. I have a position:fixed div which acts as a header.

However, thIs doesn't work as it should. Instead of actually moving with the scroll wheel on the blackberry, it jumps down after the scroll wheel is released.

How can I achieve a normal scrolling and fixed header on the blackberry, like on a computer, through css or any other means?

Thanks.

N.B. I have not been able to test other phones.

Comment: According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html), this is how it always deals with `position:fixed`. So at least BB doesn't consider it a bug.

Comment: Perhaps [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) can help you out.

Comment: Which version you are using? Because If the version is V5.0 then BB provides default Scrolling then you have to add the attribute "overflow:scroll;". If you are using V6.0 there is no default scrolling for this. So, you have to use "iScroll" or "ScrollButton.js" file.

Comment: @alishaik786 I am using BB V7.0.XXX

Comment: Greater than V5.0 use the "iScroll" that is suggested by  mblase75. I think you should remove the "position:fixed" rather than this use "position: absolute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this one is always a hard ask, mobiles use the viewport differently, they render the whole page as sort of an image, then your viewport moves up and down that image.

I havnt tested this on a blackberry, but got it working on iPhone and iPad using jQuery stuff, feel free to check out the source: http://trans.worldvision.com.au/ChildSponsorship/ChildSearch.aspx hope it works on blackberry ans is a help to you.